# Insert form data into two database tables

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am looking to post data into two database tables from a single form.
My databases are arranged as below:

**Database 1 - 'watchlists'**:

- watchlist_id
- user_id
- name
- description
- category

**Database 2 - 'watchlist_films'**:

- watchlist_id
- film_id

My current MySQL query looks like this: `$query = "INSERT INTO watchlist_films (watchlist_id, film_id) VALUES ('$watchlist_name['watchlist_id']', '$rt_id') WHERE watchlists ('watchlist_id') = " . $watchlist_name['watchlist_id'];`, but I'm not sure if there's got to be some form of `INNER JOIN` somewhere?

Not sure what other information/code to provide, so I apologise if there's too little detail here, but, if there's anything else which is needed, just drop me a comment and I'll put up anything else which is required. I'm a relative PHP newbie, so apologies if this seems like a really simple question!

**Update based on comments**:

I have now got half of my query working, and have updated the logic to reflect it. The new query is basically doing the following:

- `INSERT` new Watchlist to `'watchlists'` table
- `SELECT watchlist_id` of new Watchlist from `'watchlists'` table `WHERE watchlist_name = $watchlist_name` (name of new Watchlist just created) and `user_id = $user_id`
- `INSERT watchlist_id` (selected from previous query) AND `film_id` into `'watchlist_films'` table

based on your comments, my queries now look like so:

```
if ($submit == 'Submit') {
        require_once("db_connect.php");

        $watchlist_name = clean_string($_POST['watchlist-name']);
        $watchlist_description = clean_string($_POST['watchlist-description']);
        $watchlist_category = $_POST['watchlist-category'];

        $addWatchlist_bad_message = '';
        $addWatchlist_good_message = '';

        if ($db_server) {
            if (!empty($watchlist_name)) {
                $watchlist_name = clean_string($watchlist_name);
                $watchlist_description = clean_string($watchlist_description);
                mysql_select_db($db_database);

                // Insert new Watchlist into Watchlist index
                $insert_new_watchlist = "INSERT INTO watchlists (user_id, name, description, category) VALUES ('$user_id', '$watchlist_name', '$watchlist_description', '$watchlist_category')";
                mysql_query($insert_new_watchlist) or die("Insert failed. " . mysql_error() . "<br />" . $insert_new_watchlist);

                // Select new Watchlist ID
                $select_new_watchlist = "SELECT watchlist_id FROM watchlists WHERE name = " . $watchlist_name;
                $new_watchlist_id = mysql_query($select_new_watchlist) or die("Insert failed. " . mysql_error() . "<br />" . $select_new_watchlist);

                // Add film to new Watchlist
                $add_new_film = "INSERT INTO watchlist_films (watchlist_id, film_id) VALUES ('$new_watchlist_id', '$rt_id')";
                mysql_query($add_new_film) or die("Insert failed. " . mysql_error() . "<br />" . $add_new_film);
                $addWatchlist_good_message = '<div class="alert alert-success">Watchlist created successfully!</div>';?>
                <script>
                    $('a.add-watchlist').trigger('click');
                </script><?php 
            }
        } else {
            $addWatchlist_bad_message = '<div class="alert alert-error">Error: could not connect to the database.</div.';?>
            <script>
                $('a.add-watchlist').trigger('click');
            </script><?php
        }
        require_once("db_close.php");
    }
```

My query, however, seems to be failing at the SELECT statement, in between adding the new Watchlist to the Watchlist index and adding the film to the newly created Watchlist.

Answer (score 2):

```
try this


$query1 = "INSERT INTO watchlist_films (watchlist_id, film_id) 
VALUES ('" . $watchlist_name['watchlist_id'] . "', '$rt_id')"; 

 $query2= "INSERT INTO watchlists ('watchlist_id') 
VALUES (" . $watchlist_name['watchlist_id'] . ")";

$result = mysqli_multi_query($query1, $query2);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've updated my original post to give new information, based on your help!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write an INSERT for each table.

```
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO watchlist_films (watchlist_id, film_id) 
  VALUES ('" . $watchlist_name['watchlist_id'] . "', '$rt_id')");
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO watchlists ('watchlist_id') 
  VALUES (" . $watchlist_name['watchlist_id'] . ")");
```

Comment: So would this be "$query = INSERT INTO watchlist_films (watchlist_id, film_id) VALUES ('$watchlist_name['watchlist_id']', '$rt_id') AND INSERT INTO watchlists ('watchlist_id') VALUES ($watchlist_name['watchlist_id']);"?

Comment: Almost, two seperate queries. Which you will have to send to the server using two query calls.